# Temporary file write failure on MySQL

Tags: mysql

When running an `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ...` I get:

```
Error Code : 1878
Message    : Temporary file write failure.
```

And on log_error (/DATA/mysql/.err)

```
2016-06-29 17:27:01 7f11f08a7700 InnoDB: Error: Write to file (merge) failed at offset 3145728.
InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 327680 were written.
InnoDB: Operating system error number 0.
InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
InnoDB: Error number 0 means 'Success'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
```

**Context**

- I'm running MySQL on a VM. Guest is SuSE, host is Windows 7.
- Got the error after having dropped the schema and recreating it from a dump.
- I had the same error one day ago (except the statement was a `create index`), and it just spontaneously stopped happening. But this time it's happening for a while.
- If I keep retrying, the count of bytes written in the logs gets smaller every once in a while.

Comment: Could it be that you don't have enough disk space to perform this operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's likely the disk space is the root cause. Watch the space free in the tmpdir location whilst the ALTER is running.

Comment: You were right. I was rejecting that possibility before because the /DATA filesystem (where mysql is) had plenty of space. But /tmp is in the root, and it was running out of it.

Comment: Change the MySQL variable `tmpdir` to point to somewhere in the main fs.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using docker and docker-compose you can add a line to your volumes to a spot where you have more disk space. E.g.,

```
volumes:
  - /data/mysql_tmp:/tmp
```

Again, this will allow you to get more than the default tmp space you need and is helpful if that table you are ALTER-ing is big (over 1.9 GB) as our docker had like 3.8GB `/tmp`